# Set custom window size for Media Player Classic/Windows Media Player

Tags: windows-7, windows, video, windows-media-player, media-player-classic

When opening Video files on Media Player Classic or WMP, is there any setting we could set so it will always open in the same window size?

Currently what happens is, it automatically adjusts its window size according the resolution of the video and therefore I have to manually adjust it to the size I prefer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Purportedly there is no in-built option for this.
If you're willing to get MPC again apparently there has been [an update](https://trac.mpc-hc.org/ticket/266) that addresses this.

There is a <sub>community-made</sub> [utility](http://forum.dead-code.org/index.php?topic=3929.0) ([download](http://forum.dead-code.org/index.php?topic=3929.0)) for WMP, however.
I can't vouch for it but apparently it [did the trick for this fellow](http://www.xtremesystems.org/forums/showthread.php?238080-Win7-Windows-Media-Player-Window-Size). It might just force fullscreen everytime instead of a fixed window size.

Answer (score 10):

For Media Player Classic:

1. Go to Options → Playback → uncheck *Autozoom*
2. Go to Options → Player → check *Remember last window size*

Answer (score 1):

Do the following steps:
Press `View` -> `Options` -> `Playback` -> `Output` -> uncheck `Auto-Zoom` -> `Apply` -> `OK`

Comment: In the latest version (`1.9.1.34`) of MPC, the _Auto-Zoom_ option is in the _Playback_ section, not in the _Output_.

Answer (score 0):

Open an MP3 file, Press Ctrl+3 to go to Now Playing view, Resize the window, then close WMP. The next time you double click a movie file, the window opens at the size set while playing the MP3 file.

Answer (score -2):

1. Go to Video --> Video Size
2. In Video Size uncheck both of the "Fit Player to..." options
3. Reset video size to 200%
4. Play back a video
5. Go back and reset video size back to 100%

This should refresh the video size back to its original dimensions.